# How to test axios requests in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

I want to test axios requests in jest.
The problem is I've searched a lot of ways but did not understand bunch of them and I'm stuck.
For example here is me get request

```
  componentDidMount() {
const { getAll, setPageCount } = this.props.actions;
axios
  .get(`http://localhost:8080/${localStorage.getItem("username")}`, {
    headers: {
      "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("auth-token"),
    },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    getAll(res.data);
    setPageCount();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("-----token", localStorage.getItem("auth-token"));
    console.log("err", err);
  });
  }
```

How can I test in jest?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For the Jest test do you want the API to actually call; send a request to an endpoint or simply mock the axios API?

Comment: Mock axios API.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Mock Modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `spyOn` to mock a promise for that.
Example for the eventual completion:

```
test('Test', async () => {
    const props = {
      actions: {
        getAll: jest.fn(),
        setPageCount: jest.fn()
      }
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent {...props} />);
    const getSpySuccess = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockImplementation(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve({
          data:{}
        });
      });
    });
    
    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
    
    await wrapper.update();
    
    expect(getSpySuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(props.actions.getAll).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(props.actions.setPageCount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(getSpySuccess).toBeCalledWith(
      `http://localhost:8080/${localStorage.getItem("username")}`
    );
});
```